# How to use phpspellcheck with sql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop, spell-checking

I am trying to use an array with `phpspellcheck` but it seems like it is not picking up anything from the array that I have created from `mysql`. It works just fine with an array I manually created. Is there any suggestions? I could easily use a text file but it takes so much time to load since there are 40,000+ words I need to add to the dictionary.

Here's my function

```
public function get_new_words(){
    $sql = "SELECT field FROM table";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $words = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $words[] = $row['field'];
    }
    return $words;
    }
```

Here is how I call the function for the phpspellcheck

```
$getWords = get_new_words();
/* other script to make spell check run is here */
$spellcheckObject ->AddCustomDictionaryFromArray($getWords);
```

Thank you

Comment: `print_r($getWords);` is it what you expect ? passing an array of 40k may be an issue see what happens when you give it a smaller chunk

Comment: Yes, it is returning values like `Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] =>three)`

Comment: ok, I limited the results to only 100 and still nothing. :-/